# is iOS beta software tied up to certain country?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I have bought Korean version of iPhone 5S not in Korea, and there is a problem. Korean and Japanese iPhones have no option to shoot on camera silently due to the local laws. Silent mode is locked up deeply in firmware, so the only solution I see, is to download iOS firmware from iOS Dev Center and install it to my iPhone from scratch. However I don't know, is iOS beta software is tied up with certain country? Will this solve my problem?